# Microsoft's Text Analytics API (v2.1) - Wrongly detects french word "Bonjour" as English

Tags: api, text, analytics

I am using the Microsoft's Text Analytics API (v2.1) to detect which language the user is writing in to talk to my chatbot.

When making a request to the api using word "Bonjour", the api returns "English" as the detected language.
Has any one come across this issue? Is there a configuration that I did not do well?

Please see request and response to the call below :

Request :

```
POST https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.1/languages HTTP/1.1
Host: centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 

{
  "documents": [
    {

      "id": "2",
      "text": "Bonjour"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response :

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-ms-transaction-count: 1
CSP-Billing-Usage: CognitiveServices.TextAnalytics.BatchScoring|1
x-aml-ta-request-id: 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
apim-request-id: 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 11:25:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "documents": [{
    "id": "2",
    "detectedLanguages": [{
      "name": "English",
      "iso6391Name": "en",
      "score": 1.0
    }]
  }],
  "errors": []
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same thing

Comment: Hello Bill,

No.